# In App Purchase - Options after payment is successful

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I have successfully implemented IAP in one of my apps.

At the moment I am using `NotificationCenter` to notify my `UIViewController` when the item is purchased, which works:

```
func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    for transaction in transactions {
        print(transaction.transactionState.status(), transaction.payment.productIdentifier)
        switch transaction.transactionState {
        case .purchasing: break
        case .purchased:
            print("purhcsed")
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "Cvpurchased"), object: nil, userInfo: nil)
            queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
        default:
            print("updatedTransactions")
            queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that I would like to wait that the user push "OK" on the "You're all set" alert before performing the next action.

[image]

I was looking for a delegate method but I can't find anything in the apple documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via using `applicationState` of `UIApplication` as workaround.

When purchase is completed, if `applicationState` is `inactive`, wait until state is changed to `active` (**Ok** button is tapped), then do your stuff.

You can use `applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication)` delegate or `UIApplicationDidBecomeActive` notification to handle state change.